# java : command not find

Tags: java, centos

i have a problem with install jdk on my centos.

i did install "java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.25-3.b17.el6_6.i386" but yet when i run "java -version", i see this error:

```
[root@JAVA java]# java -version

-bash: java: command not found
```

i set $PATH variable too:

```
[root@JAVA java]# echo $PATH

/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin:/root/bin:/root/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.25-3.b17.el6_6.i386/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.25-3.b17.el6_6.i386/jre/bin/
```

what is wrong? i really tried to search. :(
plz help me.

**update**:
i locate for jre and this return:

```
[root@JAVA java]# locate jre
/etc/alternatives/jre
/etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0
/etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0_exports
/etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0_openjdk
/etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0_openjdk_exports
/etc/alternatives/jre_exports
/etc/alternatives/jre_openjdk
/etc/alternatives/jre_openjdk_exports
/usr/lib/jvm/jre
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.25-3.b17.el6_6.i386
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-openjdk
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.25-3.b17.el6_6.i386/jre
/usr/lib/jvm-exports/jre
/usr/lib/jvm-exports/jre-1.7.0
/usr/lib/jvm-exports/jre-1.7.0-openjdk
/usr/lib/jvm-exports/jre-1.8.0
/usr/lib/jvm-exports/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.25-3.b17.el6_6.i386
/usr/lib/jvm-exports/jre-openjdk
/var/lib/alternatives/jre_1.7.0
/var/lib/alternatives/jre_1.8.0
/var/lib/alternatives/jre_1.8.0_openjdk
/var/lib/alternatives/jre_openjdk
```

which that is current path?

**update 2:**

```
[root@JAVA java]# yum list installed| grep java
java-1.7.0-openjdk.i686  1:1.7.0.65-2.5.1.2.el6_5
java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.i686
java-1.8.0-openjdk.i686  1.8.0.25-3.b17.el6_6
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.i686
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.i686
tzdata-java.noarch       2014h-1.el6     @updates
[root@JAVA java]# find / -name "java"
/usr/share/bash-completion/java
/usr/share/java
/usr/lib/java
/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.25-3.b17.el6_6.i386/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java
/usr/bin/java
/var/lib/alternatives/java
/etc/alternatives/java
/etc/pki/java
/etc/java
```

Comment: Path contains JRE bin not JDK bin.. update it and that should work.

Comment: @starlord : i locate jre in my server and i get several path.i don't know which that is current path.the above path is jdk? really?

Comment: please try "yum list installed| grep java"       and                     find / -name "java"

Comment: @starlord : i do that.i add the result to question.please see update 2.

Comment: /usr/bin/java -version should work. or else check the executable permission.

Comment: @starlord : [root@JAVA bin]# /usr/bin/java -version
-bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory

Comment: could be file permission.       # ls -all /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 26 Sep 16  2013 /usr/bin/java

Comment: @starlord : yes.it have that permission exactly.

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/357001/etc-environment-line-2-path-no-such-file-or-directory         one suggestion better use oracle java

Answer (score 6):

Add below two lines in `bashrc` and `profile` files in /etc directory.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.25-3.b17.el6_6.i386
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

And try `java -version`. Still any problem please restart your OS once.

Comment: For me "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-0.b17.el6_7.x86_64/jre/bin/java -version" works fine then i added it on "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-0.b17.el6_7.x86_64/jre" *See without bin/java

Answer (score 2):

if you are going to compile some java code you gonna need to use `javac` command which is located at `JDK/bin/`. All your system is targeted on `JDK/jre/bin`.

If there is no java configured create a symlink at `/usr/bin`

```
cd /usr/bin
ln -sfvn /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.25-3.b17.el6_6.i386/bin/java java
```

The better and cleaner approach is to create symlink `java` which will let you easily update java version in future:

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm/
ln -sfvn java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.25-3.b17.el6_6.i386 java
ln -sfvn java/jre jre

cd /usr/bin
ln -sfvn /usr/lb/jvm/java/bin/java java
```

Such approach will give you a cleaner and clearer environment.

You can also try `alternatives` command - [Why is alternatives command used when installing Java on a Linux machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416037/why-is-alternatives-command-used-when-installing-java-on-a-linux-machine)

But this is not really necessary.

Answer (score -1):

i had the same thinks , it was the encoder BOM UTF8 to UTF8