# When and Why run alternatives --install java jar javac javaws on installing jdk in linux

Tags: java, linux, redhat

To install java in linux (I used CentOS, RHEL is same too), I used this command

`rpm -Uvh /path/to/binary/jdk-7u55-linux-x64.rpm`

and verified java

`java -version`

Looking at a tutorial, it says to run following 4 commands, not sure why

```
## java ##
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/latest/jre/bin/java 200000
## javaws ##
alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/java/latest/jre/bin/javaws 200000

## Install javac only
alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/java/latest/bin/javac 200000
## jar ##
alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/java/latest/bin/jar 200000
```

I know if there are multiple versions of java installed, you can select version to use from

```
alternatives --config java
```

then why to run `alternative --install` separately for each executable.

I've seen 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416037/why-is-alternatives-command-used-when-installing-java-on-a-linux-machine) question but doesn't get my answer

Comment: --install just registers it, without changing the version you are already using, if there is one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you install JDK on Linux, what gets installed depends on the type of package, version and distribution. You can refer to the following links for information about the installation location on linux:

[JDK Installation for Linux Platforms - Version 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/linux_jdk.html)

[JDK Installation for Linux Platforms - Version 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/linux/linux-jdk.html)

Once you install JDK, the `bin` folder containing tools might not get added to the environment variable `PATH`. Commands typed on the terminal needs to be from the locations specified in the `PATH` variable. In cases when `JDK\bin` does not get added, the user would need to configure it manually as mentioned in [Installing the JDK Software](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3208/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/)

`alternatives` command is being used to create a symbolic link. Here, it is being directed to use the command to add the tools like `javac`, `javaw` to `/usr/bin` which exists in the `PATH` variable by default.

**If(** you could execute `java -version` outside of `JDK/bin` **&&** not by specifying the complete path **&&** if the version and bundle prints to be as that of package you installed **){** you need not run the `alternatives` command.**}**

Comment: Lol  

* #32791202:17: error: The method `If(boolean)` is undefined for the type #32791202
* #32791202:19: error: reached end of file while parsing `}`

Comment: @LoganMzz, LOL! Thanks for notifying. Updated!

Answer (score 4):

`java`, `javaws`, `javac`, and `jar` are all different executables used by the JDK. When you run `alternatives --config java` you are only configuring which version of the `java` executable you wish to run. However, the JDK includes, for example, the `javac` compiler. You need to configure which version of the compiler you wish to use as well.

The [alternatives](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_alternatives.htm) command is, in a nutshell, used to maintain a lookup for symbolic (or sym) links. Before you can choose which version of `java` you want to run with the `--configure` option, you must first register the actual path to the executable with the `--install` option. `alternatives --install` is not installing any software. It is merely registering some paths and aliases with the `alternatives` framework. (Note: `alternatives` is not using the `alias` command. I mean "aliases" in the traditional, literal sense.)

You should also understand what the `rpm` command does. Really, it is only dropping down a set of binaries into a particular directory. This directory may be long and tedious to explicitly specify: `/some/path/to/lib/jvm/java-1.x.x-etc-etc-x86/jre/bin/java`. You don't want to specify this every time you want to run `java`. Instead, we set up some sym links.

You might also want to read up on how the `PATH` [works in linux](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html).

It may become clearer if you try tracing through the setup for your machine. Here is what I ran:

```
> which java
/usr/bin/java
> ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Aug 14  2014 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
> ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 73 Aug 14  2014 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65-2.5.1.2.fc19.x86_64/jre/bin/java
```

Comment: If its just about setting paths of different executables, then why not just do `alternative --config javac` and so on, just like for java. Still, its hard to absorb logic of setting individual executables

Comment: @djs Excellent Answer!

Answer (score 0):

These "alternatives" scripts and similar tools just symlink binaries of desired JDK version to the directories they are expected to be. It's done for all commands that should be available on your command line.

Definition of "all" depends on your distro.

Answer (score 0):

To get a different version of java JRE/JDK as default in your OS:

```
sudo alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java [path_to_java_bin] 1
```

Example in my case was:

```
sudo alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java 1
```

Then run a config to select the alternative java version:

```
 sudo /usr/sbin/alternatives --config java
```

Choose 1,2 or the option you desire

Then check the changes by doing:

```
java -version
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu use `update-alternatives`

Comment: @zmag this provides an answer to the question: it says to use something for Ubuntu!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, just the guide is outdated.

After you install the rpm, you can check:

> alternatives --display java

to see if you can see the new version is controlled by alternative, if not you need to "--install" them; otherwise, I think you can just skip "--install" part.