# how to switch between gcc versions to build torch7 or caffe with cudnn 5 acceleration (cuda 7.5) on manjaro linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, caffe, torch, cudnn

I try to build torch7 or caffe with cudnn5 support using cuda 7.5 on manjaro linux.

Both gcc 6.1 and gcc 4.9 are available. gcc 6.1 is incompatible with cuda 7.5,leading to errors when building torch7 and caffe with cudnn 5 support.

gcc4.9 was installed from AUR repository:

```
jeanpat@dip4fish ~]$ whereis gcc-4.9
gcc-4: /usr/bin/gcc-4.9
[jeanpat@dip4fish ~]$ whereis g++-4.9
g++-4: /usr/bin/g++-4.9
[jeanpat@dip4fish ~]$ whereis g++
g++: /usr/bin/g++ /usr/share/man/man1/g++.1.gz
[jeanpat@dip4fish ~]$ whereis gcc
gcc: /usr/bin/gcc /usr/lib/gcc /usr/share/man/man1/gcc.1.gz /usr/share/info/gcc.info.gz
```

The idea was to switch from gcc6.1 to gcc4.9 before compilation with:

```
jeanpat@dip4fish ~]$ export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.9
[jeanpat@dip4fish ~]$ export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-4.9
```

But when gcc is invoqued, this is still the 6.1 version:

```
[jeanpat@dip4fish ~]$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 6.1.1 20160602
```

.bashrc was modified so that:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
:/opt/cuda/lib64:
```

How to temporary switch to gcc 4.9 transparently (without modifying the makefile or the  install.sh script of caffe and torch7)?

Comment: The export command, `export CC=gcc-4.9 CXX=g++-4.9` doesn't change gcc/g++. But works with ./configure : `export CC=gcc-4.9 CXX=g++-4.9 && ./configure`  And a "CC/CXX command" can be used with some Makefile´s, like : `make CXX=g++-4.9` .

Comment: AFAIK Caffe doesn't support anything beyond CuDNN 3.

Comment: "Optional dependencies:
    OpenCV >= 2.4 including 3.0
    IO libraries: lmdb, leveldb (note: leveldb requires snappy)
    cuDNN for GPU acceleration (v5)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to change any files, this hack can be used :

```
cd /usr/bin/
mv gcc gcc-6.1-back
mv g++ g++-6.1-back
ln -s gcc-4.9 gcc
ln -s g++-4.9 g++
```

... Then it's fairly easy to revert to "6.1" .... delete the links, etc.

---

If Manjaro has the /etc/alternatives/ mechanism, you can "install" both gcc versions to /etc/alternatives/ , like this java example [When and Why run alternatives --install java jar javac javaws on installing jdk in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32746419/when-and-why-run-alternatives-install-java-jar-javac-javaws-on-installing-jdk) .... and switch version with a single command, + one setting.

Comment: unfortunately, alternative is available on debian/ubuntu

Comment: At least, torch7 is built . Theano when called from a test script (http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html#gpuarray) run in cpu mode ...

Comment: Is there a way to do this task without root access..? I'm working in a remote server that I don't have root access..